# MVN is not recognised as internal or external command. UPDATE: JAVA_HOME is not defined is error now in cmd

Tags: maven, maven-install

Whenever I type `mvn -version` to check version installed it says that `"mvn is not an internal or external command"` in cmd.

I have added images to show that I have added environmental variable and the path. do check those and help out.

UPDATE :

After having been told that i have to remove \bin from environment variable of both JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME. now I'm getting error in cmd as JAVA_HOME is not defined.

Environmental variable image

[image: environmental variable image]

Path Image

[image: path image]

Cmd Image

[image: cmd image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `MVN_HOME` should be the maven root folder (`G:\compressed\apache-maven-3.8.4`) not up to the `bin` folder.

Change `MVN_HOME` variable to `G:\compressed\apache-maven-3.8.4` then open a new cmd prompt then the command will work.

Comment: Now another issue popped up, it says Java_home environment variable not defined correctly. Though i have checked Java -- version and it works fine giving me the version of Java installed 1.80

Comment: @Naveenpatil it's the same issue remove the `\bin` from your `JAVA_HOME` env variable.

Comment: Yes done it. removed \bin from environmental variable of both JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME. it still says same JAVA_HOME is not defined.

Comment: can you post the output of `echo %JAVA_HOME%`.

Comment: it says   C:\Program files\Java\jdk1.8.0.91\bin

Comment: Still the variable is set up to bin it should be `C:\Program files\Java\jdk1.8.0.91`

Comment: i had changed in the system variable and removed \bin but for some reason problem persisted! then when i changed in user variable and waah la... its working! thanks for help your the best!